# В чем практический смысл метода SetApartmentState?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Работал с потоками и появился вопрос, когда увидел вот этот код:

```cs
var thCopy = new Thread(CopyFiles);
thCopy.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
```

Что означает вторая строчка? Пожалуйста, кто работает с потоками и может дать ответ - подскажите.

Comment: В чистом .NET - абсолютно никакого смысла от этого вызова нет. Этот метод используется [исключительно для взаимодействия с COM-библиотеками](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @SergeyRufanov многие классы на самом деле - обертки над COM...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, только в десткопных профилях и в CF. В .NET 1.x - да, очень многие, потому что ещё не было понятно "выстрелит ли" .NET вообще. в 2.0-3.5 - уже было большой редкостью(в основном в  Windows Forms). В 4.x - внутри CLR уже не использовалось, насколько знаю. В .Net Core - естественно уже нет даже возможности взаимодействия со сторонними COM-компонентами.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov вообще-то там есть возможность взаимодействия с COM-компонентами. Отсутствовать может разве что возможность их создания.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov ну и RichTextBox из WinForms как был COM-компонентом, так им и остался им даже в 4.6.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, [это не так](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs). RichTextBox виден для COM, и может быть вызван из него - в частности это используется для совместимости с визуальным редактором старых версий Microsoft Visual Studio и средствами автоматизации Microsoft Office.  Однако сам он совершенно не является оберткой над COM, а использует обычный WinApi.

Answer (score 5):

Apartment State - это понятие из COM (Component Object Model). Когда вы используете некоторые компоненты, они могут потребовать определенного режима многопоточности. Даже если вы сами не используете COM - вы можете использовать какой-то из компонентов COM косвенно.

Когда вы устанавливаете потоку ApartmentState - вы сообщаете всем компонентам о режиме многопоточности этого потока и тем самым даете определенные обещания. Которые придется выполнить если вам не нужны баги в неожиданных местах.

`ApartmentState.STA` означает что

1. поток обрабатывает очередь сообщений Windows (например, через вызов Application.Run или периодические вызовы Application.DoEvents);
2. поток никогда не замораживается надолго.

Кстати, я почему-то уверен что CopyFiles нарушает оба этих условия.

`ApartmentState.MTA` же

1. означает разрешение COM-компонентам занимать поток на неопределенное время;
2. требует использование примитивов синхронизации из-за возможного многопоточного доступа.

Comment: Спасибо. Можете привести какие-нибудь примеры для двух вариантов?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: COM-объект браузера — классический пример STA-объекта.